# Probability for uniform distribution using Central Limit Theorem

Tags: statistics

I'm told that $X_1,\ldots,X_{10} \sim U(0,1)$

So I know that the mean is $\frac{1}{2}$ and the variance is $\frac{1}{12}.$

I'm trying to compute $\mathbb{P}(\sum x_i >7).$

My solution is as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i >7\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(N(0,1)>\frac{7-10\cdot\frac{1}2}{\sqrt{10\cdot\frac{1}{12}}}\right)=1-\mathbb{P}(N(0,1)<2.19089)= 0.0142299$$

Can someone verify whether this is correct or not?

Comment: $N=10$ is not exactly heart warming when using CLT but it looks like you've gotten the jist of it.

Comment: If you are applying a normal approximation, then this looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLT should work very well for the sum of 10 uniform distributions.
As a check, here is a brief simulation in R which should approximate the answer
to a couple of decimal places--without direct appeal to the CLT.

```
 m = 10^6;  n = 10;  x = runif(m*n)
 DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)  # each row a sample of 10 uniforms
 s = rowSums(DTA)
 mean(s > 7)
 ## 0.013626
```

A normal approximation without standardization or rounding:

```
 1 - pnorm(7, 5, sqrt(10/12))
 ## 0.01422987
```

Here is a histogram of a million simulated values of $S = \sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i,$ where $X_i \stackrel{IID}{\sim} Unif(0,1),$
along with the density function of $Norm(\mu = 5,\, \sigma=\sqrt{10/12}).$

[image]

*Note:* In the early days of computing when operations other than
basic arithmetic were 'expensive', the usual way to simulate
a standard normal variate was to add 12 $Unif(0,1)$ pseudorandom
variates and subtract 6.